# Display ➜ symbol in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text in the database with the symbol "➜". When I display it on the web page, I get a "?" instead. Can someone help me?

Best regards

Comment: Check your end-to-end encoding. Protip: use a known emoji character.

Comment: To elaborate on Dai's comment: What is the datatype of that column (should be `nvarchar` or possibly `nchar`)? Are you treating that value anywhere as "plain ASCII" (you shouldn't)? What is the charset of that webpage (should probably be `utf-8`)